# Intuition for integrating $1/z$ around the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Most standard results in complex analysis depend on the fact that $\int_C 1/z \ d\gamma = 2\pi i.$

Evaluating the integral by definitions is not hard, but also not very illuminating.

The result can be expected by realizing that the antiderivative of $1/z$ should be some sort of log, but any complex log must have a discontinuity of size $2\pi i$ along some ray at the origin because of how $\exp(it)$ behaves. By the fundamental theorem of calculus, the result holds.

This is only marginally more illuminating, and we might think of something like the picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Complex_logarithm).

Is there a more geometric understanding of this?

Comment: To me, the branch cut of the complex logarithm together with the FTC is the most intuitive understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see $\frac{d\gamma}{z}$, imagine that $d\gamma$ is a tangent vector along the unit circle and $z$ is the vector field that points outward from the origin. When you divide two complex numbers, you get their relative phase. In this case, the circle runs $90^\circ$ counterclockwise across the vector field. That's where the $i$ comes from, and the $2\pi$ comes from the length of the path.

Ultimately, this explanation is the same as evaluating the integral by definitions, just presented to be more verbose and less precise!